# Link-styled button in JavaScript -- different options

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there any difference between

```
<a href="javascript:;"></a>
```

and

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);"></a>
```

?

I want to have link-styled button that just call some JS function on click, so I do the following:

```
  $('<a>', {
    'href': 'javascript:;',
    text: 'Click me',
    click: doStuff
  });
```

I know that it can be achieved via `button` tag and CSS but I think that it's much easier solution.

Comment: No difference in outcome, although using `href="#"` and calling `preventDefault()` in the event handler would be more semantic.

Comment: [**Links are not buttons**](http://www.karlgroves.com/2013/05/14/links-are-not-buttons-neither-are-divs-and-spans/) Keep the web clean, use the right element and **style** it how you want it to look. don't take unsemantic shortcuts.

Comment: Bind the click action when you create the element, there's no need for a `javascript` protocol at all.

Comment: @David Thomas I thought that the `href` attribute is required for `a` tags

Comment: @FrozenHeart: [It isn't](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element), but the meaning and (on standard browsers) behavior of the `a` element changes depending on whether it's present. From the link: *"If the `a` element has an `href` attribute, then it represents a hyperlink (a hypertext anchor) labeled by its contents. If the `a` element has no `href` attribute, then the element represents a placeholder for where a link might otherwise have been placed, if it had been relevant, consisting of just the element's contents."*

Answer (score 0):

There's no functional difference, no, both will do nothing when clicked (other than triggering any click handler you have on them). What follows the `javascript:` pseudo-protocol just has to be valid JavaScript. `;` and `void(0)` are both valid JavaScript.

> Can I just omit the javascript protocol btw?

The content of the `href` is expected to be a URL. If you don't use the `javascript;` pseudo-protocol, you'll need to use something else.

---

I'll note that you have other options, including not using the `javascript:` pseudo-protocol at all (using `button type="button"`, using `span`, using `href="#fragment"` and ideally making those fragments meaningful, etc.), but that isn't what you asked about. :-)

Comment: Can I just omit the `javascript` protocol btw?